# Thread management for Akka actors

Tags: akka

I have 32 actors running at any time but only 24 threads. The first 24 actors gets the 24 available threads. The remaining 8 threads get their execution threads only the termination of one of the 24 actors.

Can you please point me how to change the dedicated thread option per actor to a shared one.

Thanks,
cabear

Comment: By default actors are not pinned to threads.

Comment: It's better to take a look at http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html before, you should not manage threads yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This is now how Actor scheduling works - you should read up on [Akka Dispatchers](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/dispatchers.html) to get a better understanding of it.

In one sentence though: Actors are multiplexed onto Threads. That means that multiple actors are using the same thread, just *not at the same time* - it works like this: Actor A has some messages to process, it gets the Thread T1, it processes a number of messages (set by the throughput setting in dispatchers), and then lets go of the Thread T1 such that another Actor B can use T1 again. If there's more threads available T2 would be used in the same style, thus allowing multiple actors to run in parallel.

Comment: Thanks.. will look into it.. I ran a test with 32 actors from 32 clients each actor receiving 100000 messages.. 24 threads finished processing the 100000 messages and then 8 threads processed their messages.. noticed each dispatcher threads was processing different actor messages.. need to find out why the 8 actors processing rate was not on par with the other 24 actors (I am using the default dispatchers in a 8 core with min factor of 3 - so it was allocating 24 threads)